# access text in cell.textLabel.text

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

This seems like a simple thing but I'm stuck.

In my storyboard, I have a cell with text in it's label (using Static Cells).  In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I'm trying to access the cell's textLabel's text.  Here's my code, with NSLogging:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell.textLabel.text) {
      NSLog(@"cell.textLabel.text = %@",cell.textLabel.text);
  } else {
      NSLog(@"!cell.textLabel.text");
  }
NSLog(@"just for fun: cell.textLabel.text = %@", cell.textLabel.text);
```

The if statement always returns "!cell.textLabel.text" and the last NSLog is always (null) although the storyboard's cell has text in it.

Is cell.textLabel not correct?  Should I be looking at another subview of UITableViewCell?

Comment: Are you sure the cells text is in textLabel, and not detailTextLabel?

Comment: I just tried detailTextLabel and get the exact same results.

Comment: What happens without the if statement, does it log properly then?

Comment: Maybe cell is coming back nil?

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle - no it doesnt - I have an extra log statement below "just for fun ..."

Comment: Add: if (!cell) NSLog("Cell is ni!");

Comment: Of course not @KirbyTodd, that's why I started that comment with "@NSPostWhenIdle".  I just tested for cell (with a similar if statement) and the cell does exist.  Ach..

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the code and run, when the lldb debugger pops up type: po cell; then: po cell.textLabel: then po cell.textLabel.text

Comment: Also you can try the deprecated cell.text and see if that shows anything different.

Comment: @KirbyTodd, first of all, that 'po cell' thing is frickin awesome!  Also, here's the output from "po cell.textLabel" -- "error: property 'textLabel' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'"

Comment: Uuuh, isn't textLabel a property of UITableViewCell?

Comment: Is your UITableViewCell a standard type or is it a custom type you've created? Maybe you didn't define a textLabel for it?

Comment: using lldb, basically use **po [cell textLabel]** instead of **po cell.textLabel**

Comment: also during debugging, try **po [cell subviews]** It will tell about all subviews, and record available on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default cell style of table cells in the Storyboard are of type 'Custom'. Which gives you a blank cell where you can add other types of controls to it.

If you dragged a label onto the cell and changed its text, then you are likely using a Custom style of UITableViewCell.

The property textLabel is only available on cells of types other than Custom, such as Basic, or Detailed.

Therefore you should first check out if these styles meet your requirements and use them instead.

If you really do require a Custom type of cell, you will need to make a subclass of UITableViewCell and create outlets to access your label.

Comment: Wow!  By jove I think you got it!  Man, you'd think that would be somewhere up front and central in the docs.  Like maybe a line in the discussion section of UITableViewClass reference.. How did you know that, if I may ask?

Comment: It was the most likely cause because your cell exists and is firing didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Therefore if textLabel is null, then textLabel really doesn't exist :)